# 74HC595N in series error

Tags: arduino-galileo, shift-register, johnny-five

I want have 2 74HC595N shift registers in series.

I built this schematic

[image]

When I send a value to the first register, it is sent to the second one. I have same value on both. I change them (master/slave) but the result is the same.

I connected pin 9 on the first SR first with pin 14 on the second. I am using Johnny Five on Galileo Gen 1 with `shiftRegister.send(25)` to send the data.

What am I doing wrong because several days ago I made it and it worked?

Comment: I am very curious about the 3 leds on the right - the clock, overflow, and data/digital pin 2 should go at much too high a rate to be able to see anything. I have a very similar circuit (Arduino Uno, connected to 2x7 segment displays), so it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you had it working and it has changed, I would suggest trying a few changes to track down the issue. The schematic seems OK so assuming that all connections are sound, I would look towards proving the code. Maybe try a simple pure Arduino sketch designed for the 74HC595N and see if the results are the same. If not, the culprit is almost certainly Johnny Five.

Perhaps try [this sketch](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ShftOut22) which should work with your schematic (remap the I/O though to your 2,3,4 configuration). If the problem persists, throughly examine your connections because there is very little else which would prevent it from working - especially given that it did work a few days ago. Also, have you got another Leonardo to test with?

Finally, the schematic for the Arduino-only example shows a cap on the latch line - presumably for debouncing - which is missing from your schematic. I don't think you've damaged your registers but I wouldn't rule it out.